# Removing a specific group of characters from a line of text

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to remove a specific word from a string of text, this part I understand how to do but the part I'm having issues figuring out is how do I make it so I can simply ***drag*** the formula down so it references the word I want removed "Column A" compare it to the sentence where the word appears "Column B" and return me a clean sentence with the word from "Column A" removed.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We can't replicate your issue without some sample data, the formula you've tried, and why you can't drag it down. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52229748/edit) your question accordingly - thanks!

Comment: So if you have 3 columns, Column A would be the text you want removed, Column B would be the unaltered text, and Column C is where the output is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTITUTE` to accomplish this.

Place the following in cell C1 and drag it down. It will remove the text in column A from the sentence in column B and print the output in column C.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1, A1, "")
```

[image]